# in C#, changing background image of a button after click

Tags: c#, image, background, click

This code does not report any error and should have work.The button background image does not change. Any idea of what could be wrong?

```
    void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string val)
    {
        //Process
        Process.Start(@val);
        //Change button bkground image
        var button = (Button)sender;
        button.BackgroundImage = global::Test.Properties.Resources.impOK;
    }
```

**EDIT** The event MyHandler is being called from buttons created by another event handler.

```
 private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        ...
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in printerDic)
            {
                //Init
                String val = pair.Value;
                String ky = pair.Key;

                //Button
                Button bt_imp = new Button();
                if (List_localServPrnLink.Contains(val))
                {
                    bt_imp.BackgroundImage = global::Test.Properties.Resources.impOK;
                }
                else
                {
                    bt_imp.BackgroundImage = global::Test.Properties.Resources.impX;
                }              
                bt_imp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
                bt_imp.Location = new Point(horizotal, vertical - bt_imp.Height / 2);
                bt_imp.Click += (s, ea) => { MyHandler(sender, e, val); };//passing printer instal link when click

                ...
                vertical += 30;//Prochaine Ligne...

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { // runs on UI thread,
                    tabPage1.Controls.Add(bt_imp);
                    tabPage1.Controls.Add(lb_impBt);
                });

            }
```

...
        }

Comment: Is your handler actually getting called? Do you actually reach this code while debugging?

Comment: Yes, the handler is getting called. The process start and end without issue. Then when it riches the button part...nothing happened.

Comment: What is `MyHandler` being called from? Its not a standard event handler...

Comment: What if you replace `global::Test.Properties.Resources.impOK;` with `yournamespace.Properties.Resources.impOK;`?

Comment: Replacing global::Test.Properties.Resources.impOK; with yournamespace.Properties.Resources.impOK does not do anything since I am using only one namespace called Test

Comment: Pretty sure this is wrong: `bt_imp.Click += (s, ea) => { MyHandler(sender, e, val); };`, should probably be `bt_imp.Click += (s, ea) => { MyHandler(s, ea, val); };`, right now you are sending captured variables from the method call that created it, not the parameters from the click, so you are running the handler on button3. Also make sure to invoke the background change on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks Ron, It works! I thought first that the parameters would be pass in order without taking for account their name. VS did not report anything.

Comment: VS won't report anything because its perfectly valid if you wanted to do that, since VS isn't smart enough to read your mind (yet), its going to assume you know what you are doing. I'm going to post it as an answer just so this is taken out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line that you have in your `button3_Click` handler is incorrect:

```
bt_imp.Click += (s, ea) => { MyHandler(sender, e, val); };
```

What it is doing right now is capturing the sender/event arguments from the *calling* method. What you want to do is to let the `MyHandler` get the sender/arguments from the `bt_imp` click, so you need to change it to:

```
bt_imp.Click += (s, ea) => { MyHandler(s, ea, val); };
```

Which are the named parameters in your anonymous method.

The second thing you need to do is to make sure that you invoke UI changes on the UI thread. You do this quite well in the `button3_Click` handler, but missed it in the `MyHandler` routine, so just invoke that background change on the UI thread:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { // runs on UI thread,
                    button.BackgroundImage = global::Test.Properties.Resources.impOK;
                });
```

And that should take care of it.